# Gson de/serialize class to other class

Tags: java, android, gson

I have an interface `Foo` and a class `FooImp` implemting the `Foo`.

How to tell Gson to de/serialize the interface to that class? And if possible it should return again the interface.

I want to tell that in the gson builder so I can pass it to Retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

### ENCODE TO JSON

`toJson()` method [determines](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jbpm.jbpm3/gwt-console/1.0.0-Beta1/com/google/gson/Gson.java#Gson.toJson%28java.lang.Object%29) the type dynamically from the object via its'`getClass()`:

```
//from Gson sources
public String toJson(Object src) {
  if (src == null) {
     return serializeNulls ? NULL_STRING : "";
  }
  return toJson(src, src.getClass());
}
```

so just provide an object:

```
Foo aFoo = new FooImp();
String encoded = gson.toJson(aFoo);
```

### DECODE FROM JSON

```
Foo aFoo = gson.fromJson(src, FooImp.class);
```

Comment: You are right, but my problem is more global. I want to tell that in the Gson  Builder. The reason is that I am giving the Gson from the Gson.Builder to Retrofit so it handles everything.